# The cdf of $Z_n\equiv \max_{i=1,...,n} X_i$ is $(F(x))^n$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Consider the random variables $X_1,...,X_n$ i.i.d. with cdf $F$. Consider
$$
Z_n\equiv \max_{i=1,...,n} X_i
$$
I've found in some sources that the cdf of $Z_n$ at $x\in \mathbb{R}$ is $(F(x))^n$.

Could you help to show it?

---

If that result is true, what is its relation with the definition of a max-stable distribution? I'm confused as it seeems to me to implying that any distribution is max-stable.

[Def of max-stable distribution: Consider $\{X_i\}_{\forall i \in \{1,...,n\}}$ i.i.d. each with distribution $\mu$. $\mu$ is max-stable if there exists $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}>0$ and $\{b_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in \mathbb{R}$ such that, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $Z_n\equiv \frac{M_n-b_n}{a_n}\sim X_i$, where  $M_n\equiv  \max_{i\in \{1,...,n\}}X_i$.
Equivalently, let $F$ be the cdf associated with $\mu$, i.e., $F(x)\equiv \mu((-\infty, x])$. $\mu$ is max-stable if there exists $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}>0$ and $\{b_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\in \mathbb{R}$ such that, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $F^n(a_nx +b_n)=F(x)$.]

Comment: If the maximum of n numbers is less than x, what can you say about each of the number individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the event $Z_n\leq z$ for some real number $z$. Because $Z_n=\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}X_i$, $Z_n\leq z$ implies that for each $i$, $X_i\leq z$. Conversely, if $X_i\leq z$ for each $i$, then $Z_n=\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}X_i\leq z$. Therefore, these 2 events are equivalent:
$$
(Z_n\leq z)\iff (X_i\leq z,\forall i)
$$
Thus,
$$
\Pr(Z_n\leq z)=\Pr(X_i\leq z,\forall i)=\prod_{i=1}^n\Pr(X_i\leq z)=\prod_{i=1}^n F(z)=[F(z)]^n.
$$
The 2nd equality uses the independence of $X_i$'s and the 3rd uses the fact that they share the same CDF $F$.

Comment: Thanks. Could you comment also the second part of my question? Is it correct to think about $a_n, b_n$ as constants "bringing back" the distribution of $Z_n$ to that of $X_i$?

Comment: @STF I don't have any experience with your definition of max-stability. At its face-value, note $F^n(a_nx+b_n)=\Pr(Z_n\leq a_nx+b_n)=\Pr[(Z_n-b_n)/a_n\leq x]$ where $Z_n=\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}X_i$ (you use $Z_n$ in 2 different ways in your post.). Then max-stability is the assertion that $(Z_n-b_n)/a_n$ shares the original CDF $F$ with the individual $X_i$'s.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Z_n \leq x)
&= 
\mathbb P\left(\max_{i=1,\dots,n} X_i \leq x\right)
\\&=
\mathbb P \left( \bigcap_{i=1}^n\, \left\{ X_i\leq x \right\}\right)
\\&=
\prod_{i=1}^n\,\mathbb P(X_i\leq x)\tag{$*$}
\\&=
\prod_{i=1}^n\,F(x) = {F(x)}^n
\end{align}

where we've used independence to arrive at $(*)$.